# Pop Up on mobile not working- wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using the easy fancy box plugin on my wordpress site to create a pop up. The pop on the desktop/laptop works fine but on mobile it doesnt seem to pop up. 
On my site, clicking on get quote button under the slider calls the pop up.

What is strange is another pop up called by clicking the subscribe button on the main menu works fine on both desktop/laptop and mobile.

I have tried deactivation all the pluings yet i can find a reason for this.

I suspect its something to do with a touch even on mobile?

Link to my site is http://goo.gl/Yjt0qX

Answer (score 0):

I checked on Mobile size (push F12 with google chrome and select your device) and it's work

Comment: I tried the same on my side, the subscribe button works but get a quote button doesnt work